# Spring Boot ignore all unused component/beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring `@Component` that has various implementations. I specify which implementation I want to use with the `@Qualifier` annotation and reference the bean by name. The problem I have is that each implementation references different configuration values as injected via `@Value` annotation. So when I run 1 implementation I will use those configuration values and exclude the other 3+ implementation-specific configuration values in my config file. When I try to run it without setting those values I get the error:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'xxx': Injection of autowired dependencies
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
> not resolve placeholder 'xx' in value "${xx}"

I have seen that I can manually exclude each bean from being scanned and loaded like I am doing now:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {MyClassImpl1.class, MyClassImpl2.class})})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

but is there a way that spring can ignore loading all that is not in use without explicitly listing? I'm asking because if my project get's bigger I may have many implementations of various components/services that are not used at the moment, and I would rather not maintain a very long list of all not in use.

Comment: No not with how you are using things right now. You could make beans lazy and that way have late init and binding of beans. However, you probably need some conditionals on the instances you want to use instead of relying on `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Ok, an interesting approach - what would be the reason to need conditionals instead of `@Qualifier`?

Comment: A conditional will not create a bean, whereas with an `@Qualifier` you only specify on the injection point which bean to use but all beans need to be created. And judging from your description there is only always 1 being used. Then you might be better of with conditional beans.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` may be suitable conditional for you

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for. Thank you very much